# Any thoughts in PLS as an alternative to SEM if you have a small sample size?

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling

I have put a question on here before re SEM and small sample sizes. I have 3 factors each with 3 manifest variables each. I only have 90 records. I want to find out the amount of covariance between the factors AND between ALL the manifest variables. I also want to determine whether the 3 factors predict a forth performance measure. I was wondering whether Partial Least Squares (PLS) would be an alternative? Does this make sense? Any thoughts?